Android how to configure provider path for dual app storage
Two connected questions:

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()  gives me the external storage. But I just noticed that dual apps (You can clone apps for example on Xiaomi) have their own external storage path. Whats the way to get that programmatically?   I looked it up and on my phone it's "/storage/emulated/0" for normal apps and "/storage/emulated/999" for cloned apps. I suppose that other device manufacturers use different paths and I can not hardcode this, correct?

(by using the hardcoded location of dual apps)
I've read the files that were saved by the cloned app from the location "/storage/emulated/999/Pictures/9GAG/", there are all 14 showed in my app, but when I try to share them or copy to clipboard, the fileprovider doesnt seem to be able to access these files:


jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/999/Pictures/9GAG/Or-if-you-eat-the-Mona-Lisa.jpg java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

The path definitely exists, I see the images in my app folder.
Right now my provider_paths.xml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
      <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
      <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
      <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
      <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>


What do I need to add? Or is the problem something different?

My guess is that it’s a permissions issue. As of API 19, apps don’t have privileges to access files outside of their own application directory by default, and the application directory of the cloned app likely counts as outside the app’s own application directory. You would at minimum need the “READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” permission to access those files, and possibly some other permissions as well depending on what it is you are trying to do.

I can read the files in the "normal" external storage and I can share them. Only the second external storage that was created by the dual apps features is problematic. Please read the question again carefully.  /storage/emulated/0/  is fully accesible for my app. I declared the permissions and configured the provider path for it. I need the same for the second external storage now if it's possible
